# Shap rendering in Databricks

Tags: matplotlib, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to visualise the Shap indices to explain an xgboost machine learning model. Can achieve this in google collab but am having difficulty achieving the same in Databricks.

```
import shap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import xgboost as xgb

df = pd.read_csv("/dbfs/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv").iloc[:,1:]

#label encode the categorical features:
df = pandasData.copy() 
df["clarity"] = df["clarity"].astype('category')
df["color"] = df["color"].astype('category')
df["cut"] = df["cut"].astype('category')

df["clarity_cat"] = df["clarity"].cat.codes
df["color_cat"] = df["color"].cat.codes
df["cut_cat"] = df["cut"].cat.codes
df= df.drop(["clarity","color","cut"],axis = 1)

Y = df['price']
X = df.drop(['price'], axis=1)

X_traintest, X_valid, Y_traintest, Y_valid = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=7)

model = xgb.XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=3161, max_depth=3)
model.fit(X_traintest, Y_traintest, eval_metric="rmse", verbose = False)
```

At the moment this works

```
shap.initjs() # load JS visualization code to notebook

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model) # explain the model's predictions using SHAP values

shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_traintest)
    shap_explain = shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], X.iloc[0,:]) # visualize the first prediction's explanation
    display(shap_display)
```

And produces [image]

This does not work (but did in Colab):

```
shap.initjs()
shap_display = shap.dependence_plot('y', shap_values, X_traintest)
display(shap_display) #tried matplotlib=True/False)
```

And ends up looking like this

[image]

When it should look like this

[image]

Comment: Please check the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71304798/9640885

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this works?

`displayHTML(shap_display.to_html()`